# My VBA program seems to be skipping or not reading a certain line in my code

Tags: vba

I am trying to make a simple VBA program that asks the user to input their blood pressure and based on the number it will out put a message saying, whether you have high,low,normal, or critical blood pressure.
Here is what I have;

```
    Dim bPressure As Integer


    bPressure = InputBox("Please type in your blood pressure")

   If bPressure <= 120 Then
   MsgBox ("Your blood pressure is normal")


   ElseIf bPressure <= 129 Or bPressure >= 120 Then
   MsgBox ("Your blood pressure is elevated")


   ElseIf bPressure <= 139 Or bPressure >= 130 Then
   MsgBox ("You have high blood pressure")


   ElseIf bPressure >= 180 Then
   MsgBox ("You blood pressure is critical!")

   End If
```

But if you type in 135 as your blood pressure it outputs "You have elevated blood pressure" instead of "You have high blood pressure". Why is it not reading the line? What am I missing?

Thanks for the help and or suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to detect values that fall within a range, you should use 'And' not 'Or'.

And means both conditions must be true in order to proceed to the code after the Then.  Or means either condition can be true to proceed to the code after the Then.

Because 135 is >= 120 and you are using 'Or' the message you received is shown.

For ease of reading I would also suggest you put the lower end of the range first:

```
   If bPressure < 120 Then
   MsgBox ("Your blood pressure is normal")


   ElseIf bPressure >= 120 And bPressure <= 129 Then
   MsgBox ("Your blood pressure is elevated")


   ElseIf bPressure >=130 And bPressure <= 139 Then
   MsgBox ("You have high blood pressure")


   ElseIf bPressure >= 140 Then
   MsgBox ("You blood pressure is critical!")

   End If
```

I also altered your last value to 140, otherwise anyone with a BP between 140 and 179 would not see a message.  You could also add a range for too low, but I'm sure you can work that out :D

Answer (score 0):

### Blood Pressure

[image]

- `Application.InputBox` offers a more flexible way to retrieve an input.
- The second conditions in your code are unnecessary, because they are already covered by the previous condition.
- `120` is covered in the first and second conditions, so in the second it will never happen.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub BloodPressure()
    
    Dim bPressure As Variant
    Dim CancelMsg As Variant
    
showInputBox:
    bPressure = Application _
      .InputBox(Prompt:="Please type in your blood pressure", _
                Title:="Blood Pressure Evaluation", _
                Type:=1) ' 1 means number.
    
    ' User pressed 'Cancel'.
    If bPressure = False Then
        CancelMsg = MsgBox(Prompt:="Are you sure you want to cancel?", _
                           Buttons:=vbExclamation + vbYesNo, _
                           Title:="Cancel Evaluation")
        If CancelMsg = vbNo Then
            GoTo showInputBox
        Else
            MsgBox "You canceled.", vbExclamation, "Cancel"
            GoTo ProcExit
        End If
    End If
   
    ' User input a number.
    If bPressure < 120 Then
        MsgBox "Your blood pressure is normal.", _
               vbInformation, "Blood Pressure"
    ElseIf bPressure < 130 Then
        MsgBox "Your blood pressure is elevated.", _
               vbExclamation, "Blood Pressure"
    ElseIf bPressure < 140 Then
        MsgBox "You have high blood pressure (Stage 1).", _
               vbExclamation, "Blood Pressure"
    ElseIf bPressure <= 180 Then
        MsgBox "You have high blood pressure (Stage 2).", _
               vbCritical, "Blood Pressure"
    ElseIf bPressure > 180 Then
        MsgBox "Your blood pressure is critical!", _
               vbCritical, "Blood Pressure"
    End If

ProcExit:

End Sub
```

Comment: Fixed the redundant condition but left the others for readability only.  It's a coin toss as to whether than is good or bad I suppose.